# MariaDB "select user, host from mysql.user" frozen

Tags: mariadb

- database version: 10.6.15-MariaDB
- os version: centos 7

I can run `select * from mysql.user` without any problem, it's very fast to response.

However, `select user, host from mysql.user` frozen forever; By frozen, I mean there's no output at all in terminal.

(`select user from mysql.user`, `select host from mysql.user` also doesn't work).

But `select password, user, host from mysql.user` is ok.

I really don't understand. Can anybody help?

Comment: Connect from another terminal (as the same user or 'root'); does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The processlist shows: `|  59 | root | localhost | mysql | Query   |    8 | Sending data | select user from user |    0.000 |`

Comment: Hmmm..  That shows 8 seconds, which seems long.